# Class 'ToolPanelComp' incorrectly implements interface 'IToolPanel'. Property 'init' is missing in type 'ToolPanelComp'

Tags: ag-grid

We are trying to use the enterprise version of ag-grid, but we have this error message. Thanks in advance.

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/toolPanel/toolPanelComp.d.ts(4,22):
>   error TS2420: Class 'ToolPanelComp' incorrectly implements interface
>   'IToolPanel'.   Property 'init' is missing in type 'ToolPanelComp'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is resulting when trying to migrate to their latest v18.
Your problem might be solved with the help of their documentation. Please follow the below link and look for breaking changes:
https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=18.0.0

I guess your problem can be related to Ag-1800 specifically.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, if you are tying to upgrade from prev version to the v18, make sure, you have upgraded all the corresponding ag-grid dependencies. e.g. ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-enterprise, etc.

Comment: Thanks mate, I've found it also after do some deep searching and found the changes on v18. Just saw your answer here and it was correct. Thanks